# Temporary confirmation URL

Tags: webforms

Using Drupal 8.5 and Webform 8.x-5.0-rc10.

I want to programmatically change the confirmation URL on a temporary basis and have it not affect the original confirmation URL if the form is being rendered somewhere else. For example, on a particular node I want to render webform "my_form" and set the confirmation url to http://example.com whenever that node is displayed, but if that same webform is rendered on some other page I want the original confirmation URL to be in effect.